# How to use DISQLite without DISQLite3Api.pas

Tags: delphi, sqlite, dcu

I need to use DISQLite for Delphi ( http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlite3/index ) for a project, but I can't seem to get it installed.
I followed the instructions but I can't compile the package because the file "DISQLite3Api.pas" which is used in the project doesn't exist.
There are .dcu files named the same and I copied them everywhere, set the enviroment library path but Delphi still asks for the `.pas`

Comment: Are you sure the DCU you have is for the Delphi version youre using? Because DCUs are compiler version specific.

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: I am using Delphi 2010 lite and used the .dcu files from the D2010 folder.

Comment: Double check your Search Path contains the full path to theDISqlite D201o folder

Answer (score 2):

You missed some files when you downloaded the library. Go back and get the rest.

DISQLite3API.pas is what connects SQLite and the rest of the code; without it you have nothing to allow the database connection in the first place.

If you have the `.dcu`, and Delphi's still asking for the `.pas` file, it means the `.dcu` you have isn't compiled with the version of Delphi you're using. `.dcu` files are compiler-version specific; those created by one version of Delphi won't work in a different version.